# CakePHP containable not working

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, containable

I have a "User" model in cakePHP associated with multiple other models.

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Reference' => array(
            'className' => 'Reference',
            'foreignKey' => 'reference_id',
        ),
        'SecurityQuestion' => array(
            'className' => 'SecurityQuestion',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'UserReview' => array(
            'className' => 'UserReview',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
        'UserLicense' => array(
            'className' => 'UserLicense',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
        'UserCertification' => array(
            'className' => 'UserCertification',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
        'UserFavorite' => array(
            'className' => 'UserFavorite',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
   }
```

the code below return all the Models.

```
$this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 15)));
```

But

```
$this->User->find('first', array('contain' => 'UserProfile','conditions' => array('User.id' => 15)));
```

I guess to return User and UserProfile, but it again return All associations.

Please Help.

Comment: Try `'contain' => array('UserProfile')`. **Edit:** you don't seem to actually have a defined association with UserProfile...?

Comment: Are you setting Containable and recursive correctly per book instructions?

Comment: do your model actually actsAs Containable?

Answer (score 3):

add this to your AppModel.php

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

And set a association with UserProfile. I guess it would be $hasOne relation..

Comment: $actAs is incorrect. It should be $actsAs [Cake Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Comment: Thank you @Kelvin

Answer (score 2):

you also can load 'Containable' on the fly

```
$this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->User->find('first', array('contain' => 'UserProfile','conditions' => array('User.id' => 15)));
```